# how to make submit button show a message after being clicked

Tags: java, swing

I have a submit button in java. I want after clicking on the button it will after taking user data show a message then collapse the ui pane

```
submitButton = new JButton("Submit");
        submitButton.setBounds(100, 270, 80, 25);
        submitButton.addActionListener(e -> {
            String Firstname = firstname.getText();
            String Lastname = lastname.getText();
            String Disability = disability.getText();
            String email = Email.getText();
            String Phonenumber = phonenumber.getText();
            String Username = userName.getText();
            String Password = passwordField.getText();
            insertUserData(Firstname,Lastname, Disability, email, Phonenumber, Username, Password );
        });
        panel.add(submitButton);

        add(panel);
        setVisible(true);
```

Comment: As @kleopatra said, show a `JOptionPane`.  Use a main `JPanel` with a `CardLayout` to switch from a registration `JPanel` to an application `JPanel`.  Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.